# android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false' is deprecated

Tags: android-studio

I got a warning:

(The option setting 'android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.)

How to solve this warning??

I try to solve the problem by updating Gradle plugin but it's still showing. I want to remove the warning. how do I do that plz help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try android.useFullClasspathForDexingTransform = true instead